# Add additional features to LSTM before dense layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, concatenation, lstm

I would like to add additional features to my Bidirectional LSTM neural network before the dense layer

```
inp = Input(shape= (lags, n_features), name='input')

# create and fit the LSTM network
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(neuronsl1,activation = 'tanh' ,return_sequences=True),input_shape=(lags,n_features))(inp)
x = Dropout(0.2) (x)
x = Bidirectional(LSTM(neuronsl2, activation = 'tanh'),input_shape=(lags, n_features))(x)
x = Dropout(0.2) (x)

#additional features
af_input = Input(shape= (add_features_train.shape[1],), name='af_input')
x = Concatenate()([x, af_input])
x = Dense(neuronsl3)(x)
x = Dense(neuronsl4)(x)
output = Dense(1, name = 'output') (x)

mdl = Model(inputs=[inp, af_input], outputs = output)
mdl.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

The shape of the two tensor i am trying to concatenate are (?,40) and (?,1). What i get is the following error : 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'ndim'.
Do you have any ideas of how to solve this or other ideas about how to concatenate the additional features?

Comment: I tried your code with keras 2.2.2 and there was no error. I'm also using the tensorflow backend.